# Silverlight 4 AutomationFactory.CreateObject exception when accessing from Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have a SilverlIght 4 project i wrote to interact with client document scanner and scan a document from the device.

This runs perfectly when i run silverligth project.

But When i add this Silverlight to my Web Application.
I get this error

> This operation is not supported in the current context.

And when i debug, I notice the problem is with

```
 dynamic wiaDialog = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog");
```

For any **AutomationFactory.CreateObject();** it is failing.

Not sure, How to fix this, I looked online everyone is talking about  OOB settings I have all that configured correctly.

Any suggestions would be a great healp.

Platform: Silverlight 4, VS2010, ASP.Net MVC 3.0 razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use automation factory inside web browser you need to enable this feature on client machines, see the link on MSDN [How to: Enable Trusted Applications to Run Inside the Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). But this works only for SL5. In SL4 automation factory can be used only when application will be installed (OOB mode), see another link [How to: Use Automation in Trusted Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457794%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> In Silverlight 4 and earlier, trusted applications must also run outside the browser. Starting in Silverlight 5, system administrators can enable trusted applications to run inside the browser.